# take raw streaming data from stdout into python program

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe

I have a hackrf hardware unit that is feeding a continuous raw uint8 data stream to a linux shell pipe.

For example this will pipe continous data to another application in a linux shell like so:

`hackrf_transfer -r /dev/stdout -f 92700000 -s 8000000 - | (another appli`cation)

In python this will do the same:

```
hackout = subprocess.Popen(['hackrf_transfer', '-r', '/dev/stdout', '-f', '92700000', '-s', '8000000'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

BUT I cannot get the Hackrf pipe stream into a python script. For example I may want to decimate that raw data stream or manipulate it in some way and then send it on to another subprocess application etc. like so:

> (HackRF)source subprocess >> a python script >> sink subprocess (eg.
>   baudline)

or in a single python script:

> source hackrf >> my_function >> sink application

I can do source >> sink in a python script where both applications already accept a shell command such as a hackrf subprocess pipe into Baudline subprocess stdin pipe. In other words if the two apps work in the shell using a pipe it works in a python subprocess call. But I can't get a python function between this shell pipe to alter the data using a python script or function.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about this please?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `hackrf_transfer` is a byte stream, not line-oriented, so [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) doesn't work; use [`read(8*1024)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) instead.

> If I use hackout.stdout.read() or hackout.communicate it 'sinks' the data stream.

Right, those calls without arguments cannot be used to read a continuous data stream in parallel.

- [`read(size=-1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read):

  > As a convenience, if *size* is unspecified or -1, all bytes until EOF are returned.
- [`communicate(input=None, timeout=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

  > Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

This is why I told to use `read(8*1024)`.

> Its not running errors or messages with this: data = hackout.stdout.readlines(8*1024) but I want to take this and feed it to stdout. I tried sys.stdin.write(data) its not writing but It's seeing 'data' as a list. So its captured the data but I can't write that captured data back out.

I hope you meant `read` rather than `readlines`, for the reason I stated at the beginning of this post.

Here's a sketch of working code, based on what you posted in a meanwhile deleted "answer":

```
hackout = subprocess.Popen(['hackrf_transfer', …], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# We need to start the "sink subprocess" at the outset, and that with stdin=PIPE
baudline = subprocess.Popen("baudline … -stdin …", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

def decimator():
    for iq_samples in iter(lambda: bytearray(hackout.stdout.read(8*1024)), b''):
        # convert the samples chunk for use by numpy, if you wish
        dat = np.array(iq_samples)
        dat = dat.astype(float)/255
        # dat = … do further processing, as you wish    
        # now convert data back for use by baudline -format u8 and write out
        baudline.stdin.write((dat*255).astype('i1').tostring())

decimator()
```

Comment: @user6754791 - The expression `hackout.stdout.read(8*1024)` does not give that error. What did you write exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately none of these ideas work. What I think the issue is that, the script opens a new subprocess it can't tell what pipe to use as it has no reference.For example if I created a linux statement in a shell and I pipe to a python script that has one statement in it to open a subprocess to baudline, it will trigger the python interpreter to open, it will run the subprocess statement, it will open baudline application but the pipes I suspect are in different shells and have no reference back to each other. Therefore baudline just sits waiting for data that never arrives.

Comment: @user6754791 - What _ideas_ are you talking of? I suggested only one approach.

Comment: I feel I am very close I tried what you said above it still doesn't work. The output is different. Its not running errors or messages with this: data = hackout.stdout.readlines(8*1024) but I want to take this and feed it to stdout. I tried sys.stdin.write(data) its not writing but It's seeing 'data' as a list. So its captured the data but I can't write that captured data back out.

Comment: @user6754791 - You could update your question with your current program; then we should be able to sort out the problems.

Comment: Marvellous! Thank you Armali I knew this wasn't hard to do, I got stuck trying to read in the data correctly.  I have created a boiler plate below to help others out based on your answer. I hope this offers a 3rd alternative for experimentation, something, between the hackrf_transfer command line tool and GNU radio blocks. This original question is out of order but hopefully people can make sense of it. Cheers!

Comment: @user6754791 - I don't see your _boiler plate below_. Sadly, it must have been deleted by some who didn't recognize it as an answer.

Comment: @user6754791 - Would it be possible to paste your boiler plate again?